# Why won't this example from 'Learning Perl 6th Edition' run?

Tags: perl

I am stuck on chapter 2 exercise 2 page 42 of Learning Perl 6th Edition.
I copied the code example for the problem from page 296. I am using Perl version 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 11.04. I get errors that I cannot figure out could someone please help? I will list the code and the error message below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$pi = 3.141592654;
print "What is the radius? ";
chomp($radius = <STDIN>);
$circ = 2 * $pi * $radius;
print "The circumference of a circle of radius $radius is $circ.\n";
```

The error I get is:

```
./ex2-2: line 3: =: command not found
Warning: unknown mime-type for "What is the radius? " -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "What is the radius? "
./ex2-2: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$radius'
./ex2-2: line 5: `chomp($radius = <STDIN>);'
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run this as a CGI script,  How did you execute this (what command did you enter)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are executing the Perl script using your shell instead of `perl`. Based on the fact that the line numbers are off by one, I suspect the cause of the problem is a blank line before the shebang (`#!`) line. `#!` must be the first two bytes of the file. Delete this blank line.

If that's not the problem, then perhaps you executed your script using

```
. ex2-2
```

or

```
sh ex2-2
```

when you should have used

```
perl ex2-2
```

or

```
ex2-2       # if "." is in your $PATH
```

or

```
./ex2-2
```

The last two requires that you make the script executable (`chmod u+x ex2-2`).

Comment: You were right i did have a empty space before the shebang. It runs fine now thank you. I should stop coding at night i make stupid mistakes when i am tired.

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you copied and pasted exactly what you executed.  Notice that the line numbers are different in the example below:

```
$ cat x.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$pi = 3.141592654;
print "What is the radius? ";
chomp($radius = <STDIN>);
$circ = 2 * $pi * $radius;
print "The circumference of a circle of radius $radius is $circ.\n";
$ sh x.pl
x.pl: line 2: =: command not found
x.pl: line 3: print: command not found
x.pl: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$radius'
x.pl: line 4: `chomp($radius = <STDIN>);'
$
```

This was with Bash 3.x on MacOS X 10.7.1.

Given that output, I can confidently diagnose that your script was run as a shell script and not as a Perl script; `bash` was used to run it.

Comment: Thank you for you help the error ended up being a blank line before the shebang #! .